# Does the Nikon D3100 have audio input?

Tags: nikon, video

The new Nikon D3100 has video capabilities, and a mono microphone on the front. However, I can't seem to find anywhere if it has an audio input, to enable using a better microphone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read the [specifications](http://www.nikon.com/about/news/2010/0819_d3100_01.htm) correctly and the [preview](http://www.dpreview.com/previews/Nikond3100/) from DP Review, it would appear that it only has the built in mono microphone.

Comment: Bummer, though I suppose most people wouldn't use it, and if they really needed an external input they'd probably use a real video camera.

Comment: @Evan : But the now "entry-level" "video dslr" from canon, the T2I (550D) does have external input, apart from a stereo internal mic. Guess it will make its way into a nikon entry level model soon.